# iOS 6 - My application lags when gesture is recognized and UIActivityIndicator doesn't show. What do i need to do?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer, uiactivityindicatorview

I have added a gesture recognizer (two finger tap) that detects when the user presses on an image in UIWebView and brings up a UIActivityViewController to save the image and other stuff. My problem is that when I press on an image there is a lag (depending on how big the image size may be) and what im trying to achieve is that when the user double taps on the image i want to show an activity indicator until the image is ready to be saved and etc... I may add that i think the problem is here 'imageToBeSaved = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];' after i take out that code, there is no more lagging. Here's my code:

```
// adding gesture recognizer to "website" (which is a "UIWebView")
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[website addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

// actions on gesture detect and call actionsOnImage for options
-(void) doubleTap :(UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender {
[loadingImageActivityIndicator startAnimating];
int scrollPositionY = [[self.website stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
int scrollPositionX = [[self.website stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageXOffset"] intValue];

int displayWidth = [[self.website stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.outerWidth"] intValue];
CGFloat scale = website.frame.size.width / displayWidth;

CGPoint pt = [sender locationInView:self.website];
pt.x *= scale;
pt.y *= scale;
pt.x += scrollPositionX;
pt.y += scrollPositionY;

NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).tagName", pt.x, pt.y];
NSString *tagName = [self.website stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

if ([tagName compare:@"IMG" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]==NSOrderedSame) {
    NSLog(@"tagName was IMG");
    NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).src", pt.x, pt.y];
    NSString *urlToSave = [self.website stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imgURL];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSave];
    imageToBeSaved = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    [website addSubview:loadingImageActivityIndicator];

    [self actionsOnImage];  // self made function with sharing capabilities (see below)
}

}

- (void) actionsOnImage {
[loadingImageActivityIndicator stopAnimating];

NSArray* dataToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:imageToBeSaved, nil];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform loading of the image asynchronously. Rearrange your lines of code as follows

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
     imageToBeSaved = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
     [self actionsOnImage];
});

[website addSubview:loadingImageActivityIndicator];
```

Comment: Yay...thank you :) if you don't mind can you explain what that does? I have always seen it on other posts but have no clue what it does.

Comment: Easiest way for you to understand is to read about dispatch queues. "http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html".It allows you to do things in parallel. Also, if you do not use concurrent programming, all the work is done serially, one line after another. That is what was happening in your case. The image was getting downloaded, then the activity indicator was asked to be shown and then the method to cancel it. So what you were expecting was not happening. If you use the above constructs, it helps.